# Sublime Text Advanced CSV auto justify

Tags: csv, sublimetext3

Currently I am opening a CSV file in Sublime with `Advanced CSV` already installed.

Hit the key binding `Ctrl+Comma, Space` to justify the `csv`.

Is there a way to to auto justify the csv once its opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that package, but it doesn't look like it's able to do that out of the box. As such in order to do something like this you would need to first isolate the command(s) that are being executed by that key binding, and then create a plugin that invokes that command when a file loads.

The easiest way to do find the command is usually to look in it's key bindings. However this package doesn't make available a handy menu command for looking at or modifying them.

In that case you can select `View > Show Console` from the menu and then enter the command `sublime.log_commands(True)` to turn on command logging, then press the key binding and see what gets logged, then run the same command with `False` to turn off logging. The output in the console would look like this:

```
>>> sublime.log_commands(True)
command: csv_format_expand
Using delimiter: ','.
>>> sublime.log_commands(False)
```

So now we know that the command name is `csv_format_expand`. Now we can create our plugin by selecting `Tools > Developer > New Plugin...` from the menu and replacing the entire contents of the file with the below code, then save it in the location that Sublime will default to with a memorable name like `csv_format_on_load.py` or something similar, so that you know what it is later.

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class CsvEventListener(sublime_plugin.ViewEventListener):
    @classmethod 
    def is_applicable(cls, settings):
        return "/Advanced CSV/" in settings.get("syntax")

    def on_load(self):
        self.view.run_command("csv_format_expand")
```

This sets up an event listener that only applies to files whose syntax is from the `Advanced CSV` package (i.e. just CSV files) and which, on load, executes the command.